# cant break blocks in survival minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I cant break blocks in survival mode in minecraft.

I know you hold the mouse button to break I have had minecraft for 6 yrs, and all the sudden I cant break blocks. It just reappears after I break it.

Also, I have optifine, but when I went into creative I could break and place blocks.

I have also tried, to change all the graphics settings and it still did not work!

Comment: I am almost 100% sure this is a duplicate of another question but I for the life of me cannot find it.

Comment: You should also probably not put your email online like that... and you should also probably get a better email than one that shows your age...

Comment: Does this problem occur without any mods? Are you on a server?

Comment: Are you on Adventure Mode? Survival Mode and Adventure Mode can fool users thinking they are the same. Adventure Mode only allows users to break blocks with tools.

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion - you're too close to spawn. I've had this happen on servers where if you are within a certain radius of spawn, blocks are unbreakable unless you have Admin privileges.

Either get Admin privileges (/op [player]) or just move further from spawn.